# MoreVert icon not visible material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to use the MoreVert icon to show the  options for signout and settings options on my header of application. I included MoreVert icon like this (below) and the popup comes when I click on the icon's supposed place but I cannot see the MoreVert icon. What should I do?

```
render(){
        return (
            <header className={c.container}>
                <div className='logo'>
                    <Link to='/app'>
                        <img className='img-logo' src='/public/img/logo.png'/>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className='flex-fill'/>
                <div className='user'>
                    Apurv Gandhwani
                </div>
                <IconMenu
                    iconButtonElement={
                        <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
                    }
                    targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                    anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                >
                    <MenuItem primaryText="Settings"/>
                    <MenuItem primaryText="Help"/>
                    <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.onSignOutClick.bind(this)} primaryText="Sign out"/>
                </IconMenu>

            </header>
        )
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any errors? Any 404s or similar in the network tab?

Comment: No there is no error shown. I can see the popup coming when i click at the place of vert icon but vert icon is not visible

Comment: What about in the react dev toolbar? Can you paste a screenshot of that area expanded?

Comment: @Chris have a look at updates

Comment: can you please tell me how to import more-vert icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is just related with colours, try the following:

```
import {red500, greenA200} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
<MoreVertIcon color={red500} hoverColor={greenA200} />
```

You can check: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/colors for the available colours.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot